# how to evaluate keys of JSON to match specific key and extract value for that key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, amazon-web-services

I have a very complex JSON structure in which I have nested JSON and arrays. From that I want to fetch a object(json) with key metadata. Sequence of the JSON is not fixed for the each time. How could I fetch value for that JSON?
This is sample json structure

```
{
"id": "*******",
"name": "createNewApiKey",
"start_time": 1543504061.474,
"end_time": 1543504062.059,
"parent_id": "******",
"aws": {
    "function_arn": "********",
    "resource_names": [
        "****"
    ],
    "account_id": "******"
},
"trace_id": "1-5c0000bc-*****",
"origin": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
"subsegments": [
    {
        "id": "5d680f995ca8cfd9",
        "name": "*******",
        "start_time": 1543504061.503,
        "end_time": 1543504061.977,
        "fault": true,
        "error": true,
        "cause": {
            "exceptions": [
                {
                    "stack": [
                        {
                            "path": "/var/task/node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/lib/patchers/aws_p.js",
                            "line": 77,
                            "label": "captureAWSRequest [as customRequestHandler]"
                        },
                        {
                            "path": "/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/service.js",
                            "line": 267,
                            "label": "addAllRequestListeners"
                        },
                        {
                            "path": "/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/service.js",
                            "line": 191,
                            "label": "makeRequest"
                        },
                        {
                            "path": "/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/service.js",
                            "line": 499,
                            "label": "svc.anonymous function [as getSecretValue]"
                        },
                        {
                            "path": "/var/task/index.js",
                            "line": 34,
                            "label": "exports.handler"
                        }
                    ],
                    "message": "*****",
                    "type": "ResourceNotFoundException",
                    "remote": true
                }
            ],
            "working_directory": "/var/task"
        },
        "http": {
            "response": {
                "status": 400
            }
        },
        "aws": {
            "operation": "GetSecretValue",
            "region": "eu-west-1",
            "request_id": "******",
            "retries": 0
        },
        "namespace": "aws",
        "subsegments": [
            {
                "id": "*****",
                "name": "Metadata",
                "start_time": 1543504061.981,
                "end_time": 1543504062.017,
                "metadata": {
                    "default": {
                        "inputData": {
                            "clientName": "a",
                            "productOwner": "dev"
                        },
                        "response": "Wrong client ID"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "********",
        "name": "Initialization",
        "start_time": 1543504060.726,
        "end_time": 1543504061.47,
        "aws": {
            "*****"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "********",
        "name": "annotations",
        "start_time": 1543504061.477,
        "end_time": 1543504061.478,
        "annotations": {
            "User": "dev",
            "Name": "a"
        }
    }
]
```

}

** may contain either JSON or array

Here I want to fetch below JSON

```
{
                          "inputData": {
                            "id": "*****",
                            "givenClientName": "abc1012",
                            "productOwner": "dev"
                          },
                          "response": "** successfully"
                        }
```

Comment: so a json where metadata is a property, and you need to access metadata is that what you required as output ?

Comment: Right.... I want to check weather in that JSON metadata is present & if present then I want to take that in output @DILEEPTHOMAS

Comment: Are there any grounded rules to your JSON structure?

Comment: Nope this JSON can be in any form. Maybe sometime there can be 3 array sometime 2 or sometime nothing @Xeo28

Comment: can you post the sample json with a mock up data ?

Comment: `subsegments` are the actual keys? Please add some "real" data.

Comment: it seems like if you don't know the structure of the json, you will have to go over every property in the object. this can be done by deep-diving with Object.keys() and then looping over them. But this is not an effective solution. Do you have any control on the design of this JSON?

Comment: Real sample json is edited in question @DILEEPTHOMAS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a recursive search function.

The following ES6 snippet recursively walks through all nodes in ***obj*** until it finds an occurrence of ***key***.

It does not assume that nodes containing an array are identified with 'subsegments'. But you could do `k == 'subsegments' && Array.isArray(obj[k])` to enforce this rule.

```js
function search(obj, key) {
  let res = null;

  (function searchNode(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).some(k => {
      if(k == key) {
        res = obj[k];
        return true;
      }
      return Array.isArray(obj[k]) && obj[k].some(searchNode);
    })
  })(obj);

  return res;
}

obj = {
  "id": "*******",
  "name": "createNewApiKey",
  "start_time": 1543504061.474,
  "end_time": 1543504062.059,
  "parent_id": "******",
  "subsegments": [
    {
      "subsegments": [
        {
          "subsegments": [
            {
              "subsegments": [
                {
                  "metadata": {
                    "default": {
                      "inputData": {
                        "id": "*****",
                        "givenClientName": "abc1012",
                        "productOwner": "dev"
                      },
                      "response": "** successfully"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

console.log(search(obj, 'metadata'))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking only for the first element of an array then this you can try.

```js
var a = {
    "subsegments": [{
        "subsegments": [{
            "subsegments": [{
                "subsegments": [{
                    "metadata": {
                        "default": {
                            "inputData": {
                                "id": "",
                                "givenClientName": "abc1012",
                                "productOwner": "dev"
                            },
                            "response": " successfully"
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "subsegments": [{
                "subsegments": [{
                    "metadata": {
                        "default": {
                            "inputData": {
                                "id": "",
                                "givenClientName": "abc1012",
                                "productOwner": "dev"
                            },
                            "response": " successfully"
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}

function test(params) {
    if (!params) {
        return null;
    }
    if (params.default) {
        return params.default;
    } else if (Array.isArray(params)) {
        var subsegments = params[0].subsegments || params[0].metadata;
        return test(subsegments);
    } else {
        return test(params.subsegments);
    }
}

console.log(test(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility, searching depth-first for an item with a given key, returning `null` if it's not found:

```js
const findFirstKey = (name) => (obj)  => !(obj instanceof Object)
  ? null
  : name in obj
    ? obj[name]
    : Object.keys(obj).reduce((res, key) => res || findFirstKey(name)(obj[key]), null)

const response = {"aws": {"account_id": "******", "function_arn": "********", "resource_names": ["****"]}, "end_time": 1543504062.059, "id": "*******", "name": "createNewApiKey", "origin": "AWS::Lambda::Function", "parent_id": "******", "start_time": 1543504061.474, "subsegments": [{"aws": {"operation": "GetSecretValue", "region": "eu-west-1", "request_id": "******", "retries": 0}, "cause": {"exceptions": [{"message": "*****", "remote": true, "stack": [{"label": "captureAWSRequest [as customRequestHandler]", "line": 77, "path": "/var/task/node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/lib/patchers/aws_p.js"}, {"label": "addAllRequestListeners", "line": 267, "path": "/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/service.js"}, {"label": "makeRequest", "line": 191, "path": "/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/service.js"}, {"label": "svc.anonymous function [as getSecretValue]", "line": 499, "path": "/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/service.js"}, {"label": "exports.handler", "line": 34, "path": "/var/task/index.js"}], "type": "ResourceNotFoundException"}], "working_directory": "/var/task"}, "end_time": 1543504061.977, "error": true, "fault": true, "http": {"response": {"status": 400}}, "id": "5d680f995ca8cfd9", "name": "*******", "namespace": "aws", "start_time": 1543504061.503, "subsegments": [{"end_time": 1543504062.017, "id": "*****", "metadata": {"default": {"inputData": {"clientName": "a", "productOwner": "dev"}, "response": "Wrong client ID"}}, "name": "Metadata", "start_time": 1543504061.981}]}, {"aws": {"*****": "blah"}, "end_time": 1543504061.47, "id": "********", "name": "Initialization", "start_time": 1543504060.726}, {"annotations": {"Name": "a", "User": "dev"}, "end_time": 1543504061.478, "id": "********", "name": "annotations", "start_time": 1543504061.477}], "trace_id": "1-5c0000bc-*****"}

const meta = findFirstKey('metadata')(response)

console.log(meta)
```

Here you could also write `const getMeta = findFirstKey('metadata')` and then simply apply that function to your data.

But please note that if your data is too inconsistent, any attempt to normalize it like this can end up being problematic.  If you can tame it up front, the rest of your code will likely be simpler.